# Plot a network graph defining some fixed nodes to plot graph on a map

Tags: r, igraph

I have a graph consisting of people and cities in Germany (nodes). I want to map the cities according to their locations onto a map of Germany and add the people and according connections to the fixed cities. Thereby, I do not want to specify the location for each person as that is very time consuming.

Is there a way to plot the network graph on the map by specifiying the location of the cities but not for the people that are conected to the cities? As far as I see it, with `igraph`, I can only fix all or no nodes, but not some nodes.

Is it possible using `igraph`, `map` and `ggmap`? I am open for other and additional libraries to archive what I have in mind.

Attached you find my graph layout.
[Network Graph. Blue: People, Green: Cities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59e2c.png)

EDIT:

This is the the minimal working example, using libaries `ggmap`, `map`, `mapdata` and `igraph` or `visNetwork`:

```
persons=c("Name1","Name2","Name3","Name2","Name1","Name4")
cities=c("Bremen","Bremen","Berlin","Berlin","Berlin","Dresden")
edgelist = cbind(persons,cities)
coordlist = geocode(edgelist[,2])
coordlist = cbind(coordlist,edgelist[2])
colnames(coordlist)=c("lon","lat","label")

#1 Plot map with added points for cities 
map("worldHires","germany", col="grey20", fill=TRUE, lwd=0.1)
points(coordlist$lon,coordlist$lat, pch=19,col="red",cex=3)

#2 plot graph with igraph without fixed points
ig = graph.data.frame(edgelist, directed=F)
plot(ig, edge.arrow.size=.4)
```

With the code following `#1` I can plot the map and the cities but don't know how to add the person nodes withoud defining their coordinates.

With the code following `#2` I can visualize the network graph, but don't know how to fix the coordinates for the city nodes only. I checked [this](http://www.kateto.net/polnet2016#network-layoutshttp://) link but it seems I can change the layout only by fixing all nodes, not just the city nodes leaving the person nodes 'floating'.

This is the visualization I want to accomplish:
[Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/On8Qt.png)

Comment: This [excellent resource](http://www.kateto.net/polnet2016#overlaying-networks-on-geographic-maps) should help. The very last section deals with this issue.

Comment: I saw that documentation. Unfortunately, it only deals with points that are plotting according to their coordinates. As I stated, I don't want to specify the location / coordinates for all my nodes, but only for my city nodes, so that the person nodes are plotted randomly around the cities. Any ideas on that specific problem?

Comment: Could you provide a [minimally reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Otherwise, it is hard to help you for your specific case.

Comment: @paqmo: I added it now. Sorry for not providing it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach. Key steps: (1) Use `igraph` to produce layout coordinates for the vertices; (2) Recode the coordinates with lat/lon data; (3) add some random noise to the coordinates for the people so that they don't overlap the cities; (4) layout a map backgroud; (5) add the network plot using `sna`.

```
library(maps); library(ggmap); library(igraph); library(mapdata)
persons=c("Name1","Name2","Name3","Name2","Name1","Name4")
cities=c("Bremen","Bremen","Berlin","Berlin","Berlin","Dresden")
edgelist = cbind(persons,cities)
coordlist = geocode(edgelist[,2])
coordlist = cbind(coordlist,edgelist[,2], edgelist[,1])
colnames(coordlist)=c("lon","lat","city", "name")

ig = graph.data.frame(edgelist, directed=F)
l <- layout_nicely(ig)
l[which(V(ig)$name %in% unique(coordlist$city)),1] <- unique(coordlist[which(coordlist$city %in% V(ig)$name[5:7]),1])
l[which(V(ig)$name %in% unique(coordlist$city)),2] <- unique(coordlist[which(coordlist$city %in% V(ig)$name[5:7]),2])
l[which(V(ig)$name %in% unique(coordlist$name)),1] <- coordlist[match(V(ig)$name,as.character(coordlist$name)),1][1:4]
l[which(V(ig)$name %in% unique(coordlist$name)),2] <- coordlist[match(V(ig)$name,as.character(coordlist$name)),2][1:4]
l[1:2,1] <- l[1:2,1] + rnorm(2,2,1.5)
l[3:4,1] <- l[3:4,1] - rnorm(2,1,1)
l[1:4,2] <- jitter(l[1:4,2], 0.25)
col <- c(rep("red", 4), rep("blue", 3))


map("worldHires", "Germany", col="grey50", fill=TRUE, lwd=0.1)
plot.network(intergraph::asNetwork(ig), coord = l, new=FALSE,
             vertex.cex = 2, vertex.col = col)
```

[image]

A couple of caveats--mess around with the random noise/`jitter` to get the people where you want or find a more systematic way to do it; and the plot is quite small. May need to explore how to resize the map background.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check your solution the next days but it looks quite good. Do you think there is an interactive solution where it is possible to move the person nodes on the map?